# UAC elevation- NSIS script

Tags: nsis

I created installer via NSIS. "c:\program files\myapp" is default folder for my application.Included script to run myapp on startUp.I'm having windows 7 But it always fail to start on start-up of machine. How can I elevate the user privileges to call it on startup from Program files/myapp.exe. or Is any other alternative to achieve above goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got resolved.  - tried User Access Pluggin.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to [embed a UAC manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) in your application

Answer (score 1):

You can't elevate at user login (How fun would it be for the user to get a UAC dialog each time?)

Answer (score 0):

You could launch an elevated cmd prompt and then execute the exe from the cmd prompt